# Is there a way on R to represent the alternation of these sequences, SEQ1 and SEQ2, within a single ultra-long read?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot

I have a dataframe on R similar to this one, only it is 2000 rows long.
Throughout the dataframe I have this alternation of SEQ1 and SEQ2 within a single read called "id read". These sequences alternate, and SEQ1 is always 1 nucleotide away from SEQ1, while SEQ2 from SEQ1 about 335 nucleotides, sometimes jumps and goes to 670.
The sequences are both in forward and in revers, as can be seen from the value of the end coordinate which is sometimes less than the start coordinate.

| sequence | id read | start | end | sequencedistance | sequencelength |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SEQ1 | id read | 90 | 105 | 1 | 15 |
| SEQ2 | id read | 440 | 458 | 335 | 18 |
| SEQ1 | id read | 459 | 474 | 1 | 15 |
| SEQ2 | id read | 808 | 826 | 334 | 18 |
| SEQ1 | id read | 827 | 812 | 1 | 15 |
| SEQ2 | id read | 1148 | 1156 | 336 | 18 |
| SEQ1 | id read | 1157 | 1172 | 1 | 15 |
| SEQ2 | id read | 1850 | 1868 | 678 | 18 |
| SEQ1 | id read | 1869 | 1854 | 1 | 15 |
| SEQ2 | id read | 2187 | 2205 | 333 | 18 |
| SEQ1 | id read | 2206 | 2221 | 1 | 15 |
| SEQ2 | id read | 2887 | 2905 | 666 | 18 |

Would anyone have any ideas on how to plot this data and visually show the pattern that these sequences have within a read?
I have tried plotting with horizontal lines, lollipop, point, but none of these methods are effective in representing the amount of data I have and to visually understand the behavior of these sequences.
Would anyone have an idea of ​​how to plot the pattern? If I wanted, I could also plot only a part of the large dataframe I have, but at least I would like to understand the particularity of these sequences in the ultra-long read taken into consideration.

Comment: What columns do you wish to represent what? start/end as x-axis? sequence as colour? It's unclear to me what you'd like to show. Moreover, can you include some code for what you consider ineffective methods?

Comment: I'm not sure how I want to plot them, so I was asking for advice on the best way to represent patterns.
I was thinking that even just the representation of SEQ1 and SEQ2 in the form of different colored dots would be fine. However, what I would like to show and notice by looking at the plot is the arrangement of these sequences always at the same distance within the read.

Comment: I thought that the X axis could be the length of the read and the points in the plot instead SEQ1 and SEQ2. The fact is that since there are so many points, the whole graph is crushed and I don't see anything. Perhaps with vertical lines representing the SEQs it would be better?
Sorry if I can't give you the codes I used now but I don't have them on hand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not exactly sure what you are looking for, but if every row `i`  where `sequence == "SEQ"` has a paired row `i + 1` where `sequence == "SEQ2"`, you can calculate the relative start and ends sites and then try to visualise it.

Assuming your data is in a variable called `df`, you can calculate these as follows.

```r
df <- transform(
  df,
  rel_start = ifelse(
    as.character(sequence) == "SEQ1",
    start - start,
    start - c(0, head(start, -1))
  ),
  rel_end = ifelse(
    as.character(sequence) == "SEQ1",
    end - start,
    end - c(0, head(start, -1))
  )
)
```

Then for visualisation, you can just use `geom_segment()`. You could use arrows to indicate the direction of the reads.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(rel_start, y = seq_along(start), colour = sequence)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = rel_end, yend = seq_along(start)),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(2, "mm")))
```

[image]

Data loading:

```r
txt <- "sequence    id read     start   end     sequencedistance    sequencelength
SEQ1    id read     90  105     1   15
SEQ2    id read     440     458     335     18
SEQ1    id read     459     474     1   15
SEQ2    id read     808     826     334     18
SEQ1    id read     827     812     1   15
SEQ2    id read     1148    1156    336     18
SEQ1    id read     1157    1172    1   15
SEQ2    id read     1850    1868    678     18
SEQ1    id read     1869    1854    1   15
SEQ2    id read     2187    2205    333     18
SEQ1    id read     2206    2221    1   15
SEQ2    id read     2887    2905    666     18"

df <- read.table(text = txt, header = TRUE)
```